# What are firebase analytics rate limits?

Tags: firebase-analytics

I know google analytics has [this way of handling rate limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/limits-quotas#client_libs_sdks), now how does firebase handle this (maybe a maximum of hits per second)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rate limit.  However unless you are in debug mode events will generally be bundled and sent about once per hour.